# Rename filename on uploading to s3 using carrierwave according to user input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fine-uploader

I have two models associated like:

```
class Dress < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: images
end
```

and

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: dress
end
```

And uploader is like:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  process :fix_exif_rotation
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::Backgrounder::Delay

  storage :fog
  .
  .
  .
end
```

i want to rename filename but the problem is that when i rename file name doing:

```
def filename
  ...
end
```

i dont have user input values from dress because value is not saved when uploading image. Please anyone can guide me???

Comment: You should be able to be rename while uploading image. What do you want it to be renamed to ?

Comment: I want to rename it with model.dress.brand but problem is model.dress.brand is nil because value isnot saved when image upload

Comment: Can you share what is the value of `self` and also `#{model}`?

Comment: When i do model, i get :
#<Image:0x00007f7ed8a23b28
 id: nil,
 dress_id: 22,
 created_at: nil,
 updated_at: nil,
 image: nil,
 position: nil,
 default: false,
 crop_x: nil,
 crop_y: nil,
 crop_h: nil,
 crop_w: nil,
 publish: false>
And when i do model.dress i get:id: 22,
 designer_brand: nil,
 dress_name: nil,
 size: nil,
 style: nil,
 colour: nil,
 fit: nil,
 created_at: Tue, 21 Aug 2018 14:30:23 AEST +10:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 21 Aug 2018 14:30:23 AEST +10:00

Comment: But the `dress` is already saved. Why are you not populating `dress.brand` at the time of saving the `dress` ?

Comment: Yeah dress has been saved when value i instantiated but at that time dress brand and all is not saved

Comment: Is `brand` another table ?

Comment: yes brand is another model and i have to rename file according to brand + dress_name + colour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178409/discussion-between-usar-and-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna).

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna new_sf = CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.new file.move_to(new_path) 
model.file.cache!(new_sf)
these two lines are not being executed on mine,this show error undefined method `move_to' for #<CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File:0x00007fe1d020a0a8>